# Is querying Azure Storage Tables always 1 transaction?

Tags: azure, transactions, azure-table-storage

Suppose I have an Azure Storage Table with 50K rows with entities like this

```
 {
  PartitionKey,
  RowKey,
  Name,
  Price
}
```

And the query would be something like this

```
var query = from entity in dataServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(tableName)
                 where entity.Price == 10
                 select new { entity.Name};
```

When I need to search for all entities whose Price == 10 will the transactions be counted only for the number of results returned? Or will the check of every entity (entity.Price == 10) be counted as separate read transaction what results in 50K transactions?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: The query you posted will result in a complete table scan. I realize that wasn't your question, hence me posting as a comment. But this may result in some performance-related issues with your app as your table size grows. You should *at least* consider searching within a partition (reducing to a partition scan).

Comment: Wish I could double vote that up. Great eye @DavidMakogon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query itself and its response will be within a single billable transaction (distinguishing from database transactions). That response however may not have all of the rows you requested. If the result set is particularly large, you will get a continuation token. When you pull more rows with the continuation token another transaction will take place.

Comment: To clarify "particularly large", a result set can not be larger than 1000 rows.  If there are more rows available than this you will get a continuation token.  However, you can also get a continuation token with a result set that has less than 1000 rows.  You can get a result set with 0 rows and a continuation token even if there are rows that match your criteria.  You're more likely to get a continuation token if you're not querying by PK/RK.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/#subheading25

Entities per Second (Account)

The scalability limit for accessing tables is up to 20,000 entities (1KB each) per second for an account. In general, each entity that is inserted, updated, deleted, or scanned counts toward this target. So a batch insert that contains 100 entities would count as 100 entities. **A query that scans 1000 entities and returns 5 would count as 1000 entities.**

anyway here
 **Understanding Windows Azure Storage Billing – Bandwidth, Transactions, and Capacity**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx